# PNG viewer that displays alpha channel as transparent

Tags: windows, images, image-viewer

I'm looking for a PNG viewer for Windows that *is* transparent for the transparent parts of the picture - that is, we can then see the other windows below.

It should be something like this:

[image: Normally, the transparent background is displayed gray] [image: But I want the background to be really transparent!]
<sup>Normally, the transparent background is displayed gray / But I want the background to be really transparent</sup>

**Use case**: I need to align my live micrsocope image precisely to a shape of a PNG image. I could draw the edges of the image with some screen scribbling software, or just display my shape as a PNG image with alpha channel. It seems very straightforward that a PNG viewer should support that, but I haven't been able to find one with this feature.

**Requirements**:

- (preferrably) free software which displays the alpha channel of an image as transparent.
- It would be nice to scale and freely rotate the image when viewing it

**Research so far**

- Coding something in this direction also seems possible (see e.g. [here](http://codeproject.com/Articles/29184/A-lovely-goldfish-desktop-pet-using-alpha-PNG-and)). But there has to be a out-of-the box solution!
- In [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/display-half-transparent-ghost-image-over-other-windows), they suggest using software to make one window semi-transparent. This is a halfways solution for my needs (right now I'm using [Glass2K](http://chime.tv/products/glass2k.shtml))
- In the same post, they mention a software called [Custom Desktop Logo](http://customdesktoplogo.wikidot.com/) which seems to be something in the right direction, but it doesn't work for me on Windows10.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ugly formatting. SE forbids more than 2 links for newbies like me, so please upvote so that I get more reputation and make nicely formatted posts :)

Comment: A transparent web-browser would be a particularly cool and useful solution to this.  The webkit rendering engine can do this (confirmed via PhantomJS) so there's no fundamental reason why browsers which use webkit - such as Chrome and Safari  - couldn't optionally have a transparent background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install, [python](https://www.python.org/) 2.7 & [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) plus the [Docs & Demo package](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython3.0-win32-docs-demos-3.0.2.0.exe) you will find that you have, in the demos package a demo called ShapedWindow that does almost exactly what you are asking for. *(There are also demos of AlphaDrawing that might be helpful)*

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Since it is python it is small, *136 lines,* and you should be able to adapt it quite easily.
- You can extend it to be able to change images, zoom, rotate, etc.

### The demo running over the demo

[image: Demo in action]

### Note

Work is ongoing to make wxPython available for Python 3.x but it is not yet in a released state.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but here's a transparent browser

https://github.com/Antony74/transparent-browser

(Electron/Chromium based)

[image: Transparent browser]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but maybe this would be interesting for people coming to this page while searching for a solution for exactly this problem.

[One Photo Viewer](https://onephotoviewer.com/download/) can do exactly that, i.e. show png pictures with transparent alpha channel.